# ReactiveUI how to update ReactiveList of existing values

Tags: c#, reactiveui

The last couple of hours I'm trying to solve a problem with how I can update existing values in a ObservableCollection. I will explain what I trying to do with some examples down here.

The ObservableCollection that is being loaded in a Xamarin.Froms ListView.

```
ObservableCollection<SearchResult> _searchResults;
    public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> SearchResults
    {
        get { return _searchResults; }
        private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _searchResults, value); }
    }

    ReactiveCommand<List<SearchResult>> _search;
    public ReactiveCommand<List<SearchResult>> Search
    {
        get { return _search; }
        private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _search, value); }
    }
```

And this is the ReactiveObject that is being loaded in the ObservableCollection. When first loading the list, AvaText and PerText are null, because the data is not there yet. So I want to iterate over the list and update every SearchObject with the right values for AvaText and PerText and to get that data I need to update that with another API call. What is the best possible way to do that? Can anyone help me with showing me in the right direction? It would be much appreciated :)

```
        public class SearchResult : ReactiveObject
    {

        string _displayText;

        public string DisplayText
        {
            get { return _displayText; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _displayText, value); }
        }

        string _IdText;

        public string IdText
        {
            get { return _IdText; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _IdText, value); }
        }

        string _avaText;

        public string AvaText
        {
            get { return _avaText; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _avaText, value); }
        }

        string _perText;

        public string PerText
        {
            get { return _perText; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _perText, value); }
        }
    }
```

I have looked into the documentation of ReactiveUI and I think that I should do something with .ToProperty?

Thank you for reading.

Kind regards,

Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed your Search ReactiveCommand.  That might also need to be changed.  Look at my LoadStatsImp function below on how to do the SearchImp function. Maybe something like.

```
ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ObservableCollection<SearchResult>> _searchResults;
public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> SearchResults => _searchResults;

public ReactiveCommand<ObservableCollection<SearchResult>> Search { get; protected set; }

public TheClassTheseAreIn 
{       
   Search = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(parameter => SearchImp(this.SearchCriteria));

   _searchResults = Search.ToProperty(this, x => x.SearchResults, new ObservableCollection<SearchResult>);
}
```

I believe could call your updates to AvaText and PerText from the SearchResult class.

I'm assuming that AvaText and PerText are readonly, in which case I would use ObservableAsPropertyHelper for AvaText and PerText instead of the RaiseAndSetIfChanged implementation you have now.  The SearchResult class will look for its IdText to change and then it will call the LoadStats ReactiveCommand.  LoadStats uses ToProperty to update AvaText and PerText .

Most of this came from the [example code at docs.reactiveui.net](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/getting-started/example.html)

```
public class SearchResult : ReactiveObject
{
   string _displayText;

    public string DisplayText
    {
        get { return _displayText; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _displayText, value); }
    }

    string _IdText;

    public string IdText
    {
        get { return _IdText; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _IdText, value); }
    }

   ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _avaText;
   public string AvaText => _avaText.Value;

   ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _perText;
   public string PerText => _perText.Value;

   public ReactiveCommand<StatsClass> LoadStats { get; protected set; }

   public ModelTile ()
   {
      LoadStats = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(parameter => LoadStatsImp(this.IdText));

      LoadStats.ThrownExceptions
         .SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
         .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Couldn't load stats", ex));

      _avaText= LoadStats.Select(stats => stats.Ava).ToProperty(this, x => x.AvaText, string.Empty);

      _perText= LoadStats.Select(stats => stats.Per).ToProperty(this, x => x.PerText, string.Empty);

      this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IdText)
         .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
         .InvokeCommand(LoadStats);
   }

   public static async Task<StatsClass> LoadStatsImp(string id)
   {
      var stats = await DownloadRss(id);

      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"number of stats: {stats}");

      return stats;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I noticed that my question was a bit short and not clear. So I have edited that and maybe you have other solution or other idea on how I should approach this.

Comment: I modified it slightly to work with your SearchResult class.  Let me know if that doesn't work and what errors you are getting.

Comment: it works! Thank you very much. The only thing that I'm getting now is an Refit extension error. Because I have to make so much request I get a error message " 400 Bad Request". Again thank you very much for all your help :)